# Is security of the modulus needed to maintain the "discrete logarithm problem"?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, discrete-logarithms

After a serious google search, I have been unable to find a definite yes/no answer to the following question.

Assume I have c, e and m, and I compute $r = c ^ e \mod m$

This is with regard to the discrete-logarithm problem.  My understanding is that revealing r and c does not compromise e, but what about revealing m?

I know enough about cryptography to know that I should never assume anything, thus my reason for asking.

Comment: Everyone must know the modulus, otherwise how are they supposed to do the calculations? You want to conceal its factors.

Comment: @Randall Thanks - post that as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll let someone else take it.  I’m on my phone ;)

Comment: Although "discreet" is also somewhat genre-appropriate, in this case it's the "discrete" logarithm problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are talking about [public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). For [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)), $e$ and $m$ are the public keys for the recipient; $c$ is the message to be encrypted and presumably is private to the sender, while $r$ is the encrypted message that is presumed to be open to interception. The secret decrypt value is $d:= e^{-1} \bmod$ [$\lambda(m)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), which is hard to discover since $m$ is a number that is chosen to be hard to factorize - the product of two large primes.

Even knowing all of $r$ and $c$ for a set of messages (and given that $e$ and $m$ are public anyway), the decrypt key value of $d$ is still secure by the size of the numbers involved.

One of the interesting tricks is to send a message encrypted with your own key but using the decrypt exponent $d$ instead of the public encrpyt $e$. Then anyone can decrypt it but it can only have come from you. Then wrapping this message (suitably tagged) in someone else's public key means only they can read it, and they know that only you could have sent it.

Comment: If the talk is really on the discrete logarithm problem, then the "secret message" is $e$, not $c$ (and $m$ is usually taken to be prime).

Comment: @metamorphy No, the whole point of $m$ is that it is not prime.

Comment: It is the point for RSA. For [DLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Cryptography), the security concerns on $m$ are "completely different".

Comment: @metamorphy OK added that I am specifically talking about RSA. If you want to add an answer about DLP  I will read with interest.

Comment: Joffan is correct, this is for the discrete logarithm problem, and as noted in Randall's comment to my original post, r, c, and m can all be published without compromising e, and m will be prime. I'll edit the question to clarify that. -- Edit -- I will add that I did include the Discrete-Logarithm Tag when originally posting.